# C++ invoking handbrake corrupts video

Tags: c++, video-processing

When invoking handbrake's command line interface from a c++ program using:

```
command = "HandBrakeCli -i in.mp4 -o out.mp4 --preset=\"Normal\"";
result = std::system(command.c_str());
```

The video output is corrupted (no sound, and picture is unrecognizable). Runnning the same command from the terminal works as expected.

When trying to use a pipe to the command line, instead of system, suddenly it works, as long as the video file is under about 10 megabytes.  Anything larger, however, gets corrupted in a different way than before (the video file still plays, but sound cuts in and out, and the picture freezes (player does not freeze, but the video contains a still image for long portions).

I thought perhaps c++ was cutting handbrake short  (maybe if there was a timeout on system or something), but that doesn't seem to be the case (handbrake still runs for the normal time, but output is messed up).

Thanks for reading, I'll post again if I find the answer.

**Edit:** The system() method works when I try it on its own, outside the context of my program (which is a daemon).  Hmmm...

**Edit:** The output from HandBrakeCLI starts differing from when it is ran in bash at this point:

```
[aac @ 0x7f04b0e42fc0] Number of bands (57) exceeds limit (48).
[aac @ 0x7f04b0e42fc0] channel element 3.4 is not allocated
[aac @ 0x7f04b0e42fc0] channel element 2.8 is not allocated
[aac @ 0x7f04b0e42fc0] channel element 3.6 is not allocated
[aac @ 0x7f04b0e42fc0] channel element 3.2 is not allocated
[aac @ 0x7f04b0e42fc0] Not evaluating a further program_config_element as this construct is dubious at best.
[aac @ 0x7f04b0e42fc0] Not evaluating a further program_config_element as this construct is dubious at best.
```

This repeats for 4000 lines, then segfaults.

**Edit:**  Env for bash:

```
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=xxxxxx
SSH_CLIENT=xxxxxxxx
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=ubuntu
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
MAIL=/var/mail/ubuntu
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
PWD=/home/ubuntu/ivpd_php
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/ubuntu
LOGNAME=ubuntu
SSH_CONNECTION=xxxx xxx xxxx xxx
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/home/ubuntu
```

Within daemon:

```
SUDO_GID=1000
MAIL=/var/mail/root
USER=root
HOME=/home/ubuntu
SUDO_UID=1000
LOGNAME=root
TERM=xterm-256color
USERNAME=root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SUDO_COMMAND=./env
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_USER=ubuntu
PWD=/
```

Comment: According to the [CLI guide](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide), stdout outputs encode progress information and stderr outputs logging data. Maybe redirect or capture those before you do the system call and it might provide more insight into the problem?

Comment: Good call; I added ' > out.txt' to the command, and got:
Encoding: task 1 of 1, 0.00 %
Encoding: task 1 of 1, 0.29 %
...
But it goes to 4%, then the file ends  =)  So...something is cutting it off, somehow. It appears within a loop: while(1) { /*encode*/ sleep(1); }, so perhaps somehow the loop is...interupting it?  But that doesn't make sense

Comment: Try `> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt` to see if any errors are being generated.

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped)    -->  Yup, that'll do it.  There are more error messages preceeding, I'll look into that.  Thanks for the advice

Comment: No problem. I find it curious that it only crashes when you run it in your daemon. My hunch was something that was specified in the daemon that was being inherited by the child process which altered its environment (env-vars, etc.) and prevented it from doing its work. If you post the output maybe I can help.

Comment: I added it above - I'm trying to write my daemon in perl as well, as another option, so don't look at it too hard, but it would be neat if this could work.

Comment: add `system("/usr/bin/env")` and compare to `/usr/bin/env` on your bash prompt to see which variables may be different

Comment: Yeah I find it very curious that it doesn't work here but it does in another self-contained program (correct?). The only ideas I have are differing environments (environment variables -- check them how @nhed said --, resource limitations, root paths, etc.).

Comment: Right - I'll try the env

Comment: If I remove the daemon specific code, it works.  I'm using nohup ./my_program &  as a temporary soliton.

Thanks again, you pointed me in the right direction, I think I can figure this out from here.

Comment: sure you want to run it as root?